# Typescript function accepting generic parameter and array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am making a generic function to check if a generic object has property given by an array of strings. To be more specific:

```
const staticStrings = ['name', 'age', 'address', 'photoUrl'...];
const genObject = {name: 'John Doe', bar: 'Biz'...}
```

Not all the foo strings are keys of bar, bar can have more keys than foo.
Normally in JS I would implement something like this:

```
// This will render a component with value of genObject[ss] or null
 const renderStaticStrings = (staticStrings) => (genObject) => {
    return staticStrings.map((ss) => {
      return genObject.hasOwnProperty(ss) ? (
        genObject[ss]
      ) : null;
    });
  };
```

With Typescript I am having some trouble saying that the object should be a generic object, and
that the array of string (staticStrings) could contains keys of the object. What I have tried:

```
  const renderStaticStrings = <T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(staticStrings: K[]) => (genObject: T) => {
    return staticStrings.map((ss) => {
      return genObject.hasOwnProperty(ss) ? genObject[ss] : null;
    });
  };
```

implementation:

```
renderStaticStrings(staticStrings)(completeProfile?.profile)}
```

Error: **Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(keyof Object)[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof Object'**

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is necessary to use generics here. Try this:

```
const renderStaticStrings = (staticStrings: string[]) => (genObject: Record<string, any>) => {
    return staticStrings.map((ss) => {
      return genObject.hasOwnProperty(ss) ? genObject[ss] : null;
    });
  };

const staticStrings = ['name', 'age', 'address', 'photoUrl'];
const genObject = {name: 'John Doe', bar: 'Biz'}

renderStaticStrings(staticStrings)(genObject);
```

Comment: yes this works, I have tried the same solution but I though having any wans't such a good idea... can be useful in this case though

Comment: `any` is perfectly acceptable if you don't have a narrower type that you can use. If you know that the values of `genObject` will be `string`, you can use that. If this type varies (sometimes `string`, sometimes `number`, etc.), then you can create a generic on that type.